# sybase and jdbc. Could not commit jdbc transaction. Read time out

Tags: jdbc, transactions, sybase, spring-jdbc, sybase-asa

After my app tries committing many transactions after several mins, I'm getting the following exception:

> could not commit jdbc transaction nested exception is
>   java.sql.sqlexception: jz006: caught ioexception:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out..."

I'm using Sybase with the JDBC 4 driver with Spring JDBC, and I found this link: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0707/html/prjdbc0707/prjdbc070714.htm
Could I just use any of the following:

> SESSION_TIMEOUT
>   DEFAULT_QUERY_ TIMEOUT
>   INTERNAL_QUERY_TIMEOUT

One idea is to make the transactions in batch, but I have no time to develop that.
What options are there to avoid getting that error?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your processes are blocking each other when they execute (or ask your DBA if you're not sure how to check). Depending upon the connection properties (specifically autocommit being set to off) you may not actually be committing each transaction fully before the next one is attempted and they may block each other if you're using a connection pool with multiple threads. Talk to your DBA and check the table's locking scheme as for example if its set to allpages locking, you will hold locks at the page rather than row-level of data. You can also check this yourself via sp_help . Some more info regarding the various types of locking scheme can be found at http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20021_1251/html/locking/X25549.htm (old version but still valid on current versions).

You can check for locks via sp_who, sp_lock or against the system tables directly (select spid, blocked from master..sysprocesses where blocked !=0 is a very simple one to get the process and blocking process you can add more columns to this as required).

You should also ask your DBA to check that the transactions are optimal as for example a tablescan on an update could well lock out the whole table to other transactions and would lead to the timeout issues you're seeing here.